# Conflito de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou tendo um conflito de jQuery. Eu uso um Admin, onde tem diversos recursos prontos. Precisei adicionar um autocomplete

Quando depois que terminei percebi que o menu não estava mais abrindo...rsrs

**Esse é do menu e todo o Admin**

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

**Esse é do autocomplete**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Código do Autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        <?php do { ?>
        {label: '<?php echo $row_rsOrigem['rsocial']; ?> - <?php echo $row_rsOrigem['cpf_cnpj']; ?>', value: '<?php echo $row_rsOrigem['cpf_cnpj']; ?>'},
        <?php } while ($row_rsOrigem = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsOrigem));?>
    ];

    $(".origemCPF").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

É possível usar os dois, sem ter problemas entre eles?

Comment: Remove um deles, o que aparece em segundo lugar.

Comment: @Sergio Fiz isso, mas se eu tiro um, o outro para de funcionar.

Comment: Qual o erro que dá no Console do navegador quando tenta abrir o MENU ?

Comment: Como o primeiro é custom, talvez não contenha o necessário para o autocomplete. Deixe apenas o jQuery-ui completo para testar.

Comment: @DiegoSouza não aparece erro nenhum. Eu clico no menu ele abaixa e sobe novamente. Não fixa para clicar.

Comment: @LuisHenrique Fiz a troca. Coloquei um e depois o outro. Mas sempre um fica sem funcionar.

Comment: Tiago: tens de tirar um, isso tens mesmo de fazer. Depois tens de perceber porque é que isso gera erros. Tens isso online? podes mostrar o link? Qual funçõ moveste para isso funcionar? era um problema de escopo? pois no código que tens na pergunta essa função`filterArrayForString` está bloqueada dentro de um escopo e não a vejo a ser chamada nesse escopo o que quer dizer que não é possivel usá-la...

Comment: @Sergio estou testando em localhost. Removi o `filterArrayForString` e mesmo assim não tive melhora.

Comment: Que erro tens na consola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já tentou tirar um, testar e depois tira o outro e testar?? Pq pelo que estou vendo os dois são a mesma versão.

Tenta fazer o seguinte: Tire um e veja que o vai parar de funcionar, depois tire o outro e veja o que parou.

Muito provavelmente o jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js deve ter sofrido alguma alteração.

Se for possível mande o conflito que esta gerando.

Comment: Ja fiz isse, sem um deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Deixa de funcionar tudo ou apenas uma funcionalidade??? (Não vi que você já tinha resolvido)

Answer (score 4):

Tente usar [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

```
var $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();

$jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $jQuery("#ad").fadeIn("slow");
  $jQuery("#close").click(function () {
    $jQuery("#ad").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```